# Append items to a list according to occurences in another list

Tags: python, list, loops, append

so I have a list:

```
my_list1 = ["p1", "p2", "p4", "p1"]
```

and I have another list with sublists:

```
my_list2 = [[1,"p1"], [1,"p2"], [1,"p3"], [1,"p4"], [2, "p1"], [2, "p2"], [2, "p3"], [2, "p4"]]
```

Now what I want to do is the following:
I want to iterate through `my_list1` and then through `my_list2` and create a new list that contains the next occurence of each element of `my_list1` in `my_list2`.

I.e. what I want to obtain is:

```
new_list = [[1, "p1"], [1, "p2"], [1, "p4"], [2, "p1"]]
```

I have alrealy tried the following:

```
    new_list = []
    for i in my_list1:
        for j in my_list2:
            if i in j[1]:
                new_list.append(j)
```

Which gives me

```
new_list = [[1,"p1"], [1,"p2"], [1,"p4"], [2, "p1"], [2, "p2"],  [2, "p4"]]
```

So, again, what I need is that each iteration appends ONLY THE NEXT occurence of an item in `my_list2`.

I'm new to Python, so please be gentle. I'm very thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: You mean the first occurrence of each item in list2?

Comment: No, I mean, the first n occurences. n is determined by the list my_list1 in a sense. For "p1", the first TWO occurences should be appended.

Comment: For the first `p1`, I need the first occurence, for the second `p1`, I need the second (...and so on ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, but the logic is basically correct. You just need to do 2 things differently:

1) Break out of the loop when you append.

2) Remove the item that was appended (so you don't append it again later)

Here is one approach that you can take:

```
# create a copy of my_list2 because calling pop will mutate the list
temp_list2 = [x for x in my_list2]

new_list = []
for i,x in enumerate(my_list1):
    for j,y in enumerate(temp_list2):
        if x == y[1]:
            new_list.append(temp_list2.pop(j))
            break
print(new_list)
#[[1, 'p1'], [1, 'p2'], [1, 'p4'], [2, 'p1']]
```

Also, don't use `in` to compare the values, use `==` instead.

---

Here is an alternative, more efficient approach using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
list1_counter = Counter(my_list1)

new_list = []
for (value, key) in my_list2:
    if key in list1_counter and list1_counter[key] > 0:
        new_list.append([value, key])
        list1_counter[key] -= 1
print(new_list)
#[[1, 'p1'], [1, 'p2'], [1, 'p4'], [2, 'p1']]
```

You build a `Counter` to count the occurrence of each "key" in `my_list1`. Then you iterate over `my_list2` and check to see if the key exists in the counter and the count is greater than 0. If so, add the item to the list and decrease the counter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) to group the elements in `my_list2` by second item, then consume them while iterating over `my_list1`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, deque
>>> d = defaultdict(deque)
>>> for elem in my_list2:
...     d[elem[1]].append(elem)
>>> [d[elem].popleft() for elem in my_list1]
[[1, 'p1'], [1, 'p2'], [1, 'p4'], [2, 'p1']]
```

Using a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#deque-objects) instead of a `list` allows for efficient pops from the left side.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
new_list = []
tmp_list = my_list2.copy() #only to preserve my_list2
    for i in my_list1:
        index = 0
        for j in tmp_list :
            if i in j[1]:
                new_list.append(tmp_list.pop(index))
                break
            index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it a bit straightforward for you , you've stopped it one step early.

```
my_list1 = ["p1", "p2", "p4", "p1"]
my_list2 = [[1,"p1"], [1,"p2"], [1,"p3"], [1,"p4"], [2, "p1"], [2, "p2"], [2, "p3"], [2, "p4"]]
choice = 0
final_list = []
list_1_length = len(my_list1)
for each_element in my_list2:
    if each_element[1] == my_list1[choice]:
       final_list.append(each_element)
       choice += 1
       if choice == list_1_length:
          break
```